# Could not find or load main class Start

Tags: android, eclipse

I am starting to dive into Android app development using eclipse. I have used eclipse before for java development with no issues.

I am following the ["Creating an Android Project"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) from develop.android.com and I am unable to run the app because I am getting `"Error: Could not find or load main class Start"`

The instructions say nothing of creating a Start class nor does the Android plugin create one during the initial steps of creation.

I have done my homework and searched for a solution to my issue, but none of the possible answers to my question have netted any results.

I have installed:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855
Android Development Toolkit
Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
```

I also have every Android SDK Installed as well.

One thing I did see during the setup portion of the tutorial on develop.android.com is they make mention of is after the initial install of the plugin for eclipse is to configure the plugin

> Once Eclipse restarts, you must specify the location of your Android SDK directory:
>
> 1.In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing SDKs.
>
> 2.Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded.
>
> 3.Click Next.

However, I never encountered this "Welcome to Android Development" screen and I am thinking that this may be the issue, but I cannot find where I can Configure the ADT plugin.

I appreciate any assistance and also apologize for my ignorance on the subject

Thanks,
HalbergM

Comment: I found same question in stackOverflow please refer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: update ur android support library in the android SDK manager if not updated uninstall and reinstall it