# Why need to save code before running - at Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I installed new version of eclipse Kepler instead of Indigo. My current OS is Ubuntu 12.04.
All looks fine and setting Ubuntu update the same as was at Indigo.

But some `error` happens when I try to run easy program:

```
package polymorphism;

class AlertStatus {
    public String getStatus() {
        return "None";
    }
}

class RedAlertStatus extends AlertStatus {
    public String getStatus() {
        return "Red";
    }
}

class GreenAlertStatus extends AlertStatus {
    public String getStatus() {
        return "Green";
    }
}

class YellowAlertStatus extends AlertStatus {
    public String getStatus() {
        return "Yellow";
    }
}

class Starship {
    private AlertStatus status = new RedAlertStatus();

    public void setStatus(AlertStatus aStatus) {
        status = aStatus;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return status.getStatus();
    }
}

public class StarshipDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starship starfish = new Starship();
        System.out.println(starfish);
        starfish.setStatus(new GreenAlertStatus());
        System.out.println(starfish);
        starfish.setStatus(new YellowAlertStatus());
        System.out.println(starfish);
    }
}
```

Here is error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class polymorphism.StarshipDemo
```

I couldn't figure out why this error happen and how to avoid it?
Here is `java -version`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

**Questions:**

- Why exactly this error erase?
- How to solve this trouble?

**Update:**

I solved this by save before running program:

```
Ctrl + S => Ctrl + F11
```

All is working perfect now, but **why this exactly happen**?

At Indigo version I could fixed code and rerun (`Ctrl + F11`) at any time and all was re-recompiling and executing again.
Does exist any way to circumvent this "save" part?

Comment: check in bin of eclipse if .class is generated or not

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: @meewoK where exactly is this `.classpath`? on Ubuntu filesystem...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following eclipse preference (Window > Preference)

Run/Debug > Launching > "Save required dirty editors before launching"

You can set it to "Always" to auto save any editors before Running/Debugging.

Comment: for some reason this is not working on eclipse kepler whereas it worked for prior eclipse releases like helio

Comment: @ScottStensland It is working for me on Kepler - all my java, jsp, css, js, html, etc files auto save on Debug launch. I'm on Windows 7.