# Error: Could not find or load main class Start

Tags: java, eclipse, load, find

`"Error: Could not find or load main class Start"` This is the error I have been dealing with for the past few days, no matter how much research I do it doesn't seem ot help me at all.

I know that it is trying to locate `"Start.java"`, I believe I have configured Eclipse to look for Start.java in the (default packages) package, where it is. However, I click the <kbd>run</kbd> button and the error just keeps popping up. Please, I desperately need help, any comment will be appreciated greatly.

[Update] I managed to add Start.class to my classpath somehow, I just tried every single method on StackExchange and one of them seemed to work. However, yet another problem has arose, on launch this occurs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "bgv"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)

Comment: Have you made sure that in your Run Configuration, you have the correct main class set?

Comment: do start class have main method?If yes then check in eclipse folder if start.class file is created or not.Try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: It's not trying to find `Start.java`, which is source code. It's trying to find `Start.class`, which is the compiled bytecode.

Comment: I think I have... I put "Start" as the main class. When I tried putting Start.java in a package and the used the location as the main class it didn't work.

Comment: Check for your current project in run configuration

Comment: I open the Run Configuration then select Search... Then I choose Start (default package). Click Apply, then Run but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 0):

Please check the main class in Main tab for run(debug) configuration,
it should be org.apache.ofbiz.base.start.Start,
 I got the same error when I am using the Main class: org.ofbiz.base.start.Start

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse

I hope it helps