# Can't run kotlin project

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am brand new to kotlin. I have installed kotlin plugins to eclipse. I found the simple example posted below in one of the tutorials.
The issue is, when I run the project i receive the below stated error.

To solve this issue I tried to run the project as kotlin application, but I could not find that option at all.

please let let me know how to fix this error?

**code**:

```
fun main(args : Array) {
println("Hello, World!")
}
```

**error**:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Main
```

**update**:

to solve this issue I followed exactly what is in this [tutorial](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/12/kotlin-in-eclipse-ide/) and I installed the most recent version of eclipse PHOTON but still the problem is there.

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. You can't run code that doesn't compile. Look at the compilation errors, and fix them all.

Comment: @JBNizet have a look at the update version please

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile, so you still can't possibly run it.

Comment: That is not valid Kotlin code. Please look up some Kotlin tutorials better (at least one with correct Kotlin) than the one you posted on other comments.

Answer (score 1):

if your main function is a top level function (not wrapped in a class or object)

then the generated class will be FIlenameKt, or for your case `MainKt`
assuming it is in `Main.kt`

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, that the .classpath file is wrong, maybe because you moved your project.
I found a solution for your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class):

> 1. Delete .classpath and .project from your project
> 2. Delete your project in eclipse. DO NOT check delete project contents on disk.
> 3. Now, in a file explorer, go into $yourworkspace/.metadata.
> 4. Search for $yourprojectname
> 5. Delete everything you find. It should be safe-ish to delete anything in the .metadata directory.
> 6. In eclipse: File > Import > General > Projects from Folder or Archive > $yourproject > finish
> 7. Right click your project > properties > Java Build Path > Source tab
> 8. Select all source folders, remove.
> 9. Add folder, select src (whatever your src folder is called) and add it
> 10. Go to libraries tab
> 11. Add any jars to your build path here. There should be no more errors on your project now.
> 12. Run your project like you normally would.

If you want to test your code, you can also do that online on the Kotlin website [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org).

I hope this could help you.

Comment: That could possibly be the problem... If the Kotlin code was correct, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The main function in Kotlin is different. You need to add <> wrapping the String to the function, and it should look like this:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Then your program should compile :-)