# IntelliJ Terminal - updated and no longer able to run scripts from terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, software-update, terminal-emulator

I am pretty new to coding & working with IDEs. Intellij prompted me for an update, which I allowed. Now I cannot run my scripts from the Intellij terminal.
The error message I receive is

"Error: Could not find or load main class src.MatrixHomework.java"

My pathway hasn't changed... it's still
C:\Users\General_Sherman\IdeaProjects\Assignment3\src\MatrixHomework.java

I updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1
Build: IC-192.6262.58

I'm using jdk-11.0.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536609/6524125

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891. If it's not the case, share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the selected directory configuration. IntelliJ uses the configuration under Tools/Terminal in your settings to select what directory to start in. You haven't provided any screenshots, but if this doesn't work, type `pwd` into the terminal and share it here, we might be able to see the problem.
[image: Screenshot of example configuration.]

Regardless, you shouldn't be running your programs through the integrated terminal, and instead via the "Run" tab in the top right. Remember to edit the configurations and add `C:\Users\General_Sherman\IdeaProjects\Assignment3\` as a part of the Working Directory argument. This is what a configuration would look like.[image: Run/Debug Configuration example from my IDE.]