# Missing Artifact in eclipse maven project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

When I try run the project I have this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.listactivitysyariah.ListActivitySyariahApplication
```

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3  
Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.alibaba:fastjson:jar:1.2.57    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.3    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.3  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.3 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.05 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:jar:5.5.0  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.0    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.5    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.0  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:jar:1.21   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.19  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.0.0   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact net.sf.trove4j:core:jar:3.1.0  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-expression-processor:jar:1.1.3   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:2.4.1 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact ognl:ognl:jar:3.1.12   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18   pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1  pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.5.1    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.5.1    pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.5.1 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.5.1 pom.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Referenced file contains errors (http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."   web.xml /ListActivitySPVSyariah/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 1  XML Problem
Implementation of project facet java could not be found. Functionality will be limited. ListActivitySPVSyariah      Unknown Faceted Project Problem
Implementation of project facet jst.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited.  ListActivitySPVSyariah      Unknown Faceted Project Problem
Implementation of project facet wst.jsdt.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited. ListActivitySPVSyariah      Unknown Faceted Project Problem
```

I got this in the problem tab, I check the repository folder is there

I already do update the project, deleting .m2 folder and updating the project, closing and reopening the project, still got the error, can anyone figuring what is the problem?

Comment: It seems like you are simply not download the dependencies?  I would start with running `mvn clean install` from the command line (instead of Eclipse) and see if your pom.xml works .   Then it might be your Maven settings/configurations in Eclipse.

Comment: it's still error when i run mvn clean install failed to excecute

Comment: Then look at your ` C:/<username>/.m2/settings.xml`  you might need to configure your settings.xml so you can download the dependencies.  Those dependencies are not being downloaded.

Comment: there are no setting.xml in that folder only repository folder

Comment: Please try to resolve your maven first.  Create a simple project, with a simple pom.xml with only 1 dependency and make your maven work.  Internet connection?  Proxy? Are  you on your home computer, work computer?  Do `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: i try create simple maven project add dependency and try maven install its still error

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes eclipse can give you problems without obvious reason. Looks like the problem is somewhere in configuration.
I would try this:

> 1. Delete existing run configurations. When you run the main class as "Run as Java Program", it adds the default classpath of the project as
>    User entries into Run Configurations's classpath as shown below.
> 2. Check for missing library.
> 3. Debug the Java program.

Here is some useful link you can check:
[Eclipse "Error: Could not find or load main class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Also please check this link:
https://www.java67.com/2016/09/3-ways-to-solve-eclipse-main-class-not-found-error-java.html

And one more: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093209/

Some of these solutions should work for you.