# not able to import github project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

just created project on github from my office and when then i came home and was trying to import the project on my home machine but I am not able to do it.

Following is the detail.

Both home and office machine has eclipse Juno and Egit plugin installed. I am able to do check-in from office. but at home I am not even able to import the project.

my workspace directory - c:\gaurang
git local directory - d:\Gaurang\Webdriver-Data-Driven-Framework

Now if i choose "Import existing projects" it says No project found  
if i choose "Use the new Project Wizard" - it creates empty project 
if i choose "Import as general project" - it creates the project but not a java project so not able to compile or run.

My git repository - https://github.com/Gaurang033/Webdriver-Data-Driven-Framework.git

Comment: All you have to do is read the manual: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote

Comment: See the answers in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/32407205/3779853, got it working for me

Answer (score 6):

I struggled in a similar fashion when checking out https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git

The problem was that I expected to happen in a single step. The Github project does not contain eclipse files, so of course you can not import existing projects - the other options should work, however and they don't

The solution for me was to:

1. Clone the github repository locally e.g. /home/name/git/angular-seed (import.../Projects from Git/URI)
2. Obtain a working copy as a plain project (import.../Projects from Git/local)

I think it's a bug

The result is that I have the cloned repository in /home/name/git/angular-seed and a skeleton project with a ".project" file that points to that place

Comment: there are three options to import use the third one that is import as a general project?

Answer (score 2):

You have to push your `.project` and `.classpath` files to the repository if you want to be able to import the project using the `"Import existing projects"` wizard. If those are not present, eclipse cannot detect an existing java project.

Comment: this is certainly the first place to start, not all developers will commit these, since they're not all portable-