# Adding a library which isnt in a Jar format

Tags: android

So this is the one I'm trying to add to my project

> https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

However as you can see its not in a jar format, if it was i would know how to use it.

I have come across this before for other android items and I always gave up on using them because I didnt know how to add them. So finally I came here.

So how woul;d you add this to your project? Would you have top convert the original authors work into a Jar and then add it to your propject?

Comment: you need to reference the library project in your android project. check the link http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Did you clone the GitHub repo first? If not, do it first. If you did, then check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Raghunandan, I have got the answer.

For anyone else you need to reference the library project in your android project.

Check the this link

> http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

and go down to setting up a library and then right after that refrencing a library

Thanks!