# Eclipse Error Logging - Not Showing Because of imported from GIT?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ide

I have just started using the built in GIT functionality of Eclipse and I have everything set up and working, my problem as of now is that I realized my project that I imported from GIT is not reporting errors in my Java like the local copy would. I've tried the following,

Project -> Clean

When I right click on the property files of the folder I can't seem to choose a Java Builder.

Comment: What is your question? Do you just search for a missing file or what is your issue? Which Eclipse View are you using to browse your project? Maybe some files are hidden behind filters. Try the Navigator view to find the missing files.

Comment: @ClaasWilke As I said, I imported a java project from a git repository, but when I work inside of the imported git repository errors do not report as if I was working in my local version of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you import your Java (Git managed) project into the Eclipse workspace.
See "[Importing a GitHub project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760785/6309)" as an example.

The key is for your Eclipse project to reference the sources in the git repo folder (kept *outside* the Eclipse workspace folder, in any place you want).