# Referencing a git repository in my Java File (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm creating a new Java project in Eclipse.

I want to be able to access code that I pulled from a Git repository.

I do not want to change the git code at all - I just need to import it into my code so that I can call its methods.

The git repository is all set up in Eclipse.

I can't figure out how to get my code to see it. I've tried importing JAR files, libraries, etc., but am not successful. Every tutorial I find just shows how to publish my own file to git, but not how to use a third-party repository.

If someone can refer me to an existing resource or question, that's fine too. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you need to actually clone the repo in your workspace to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. I'm pretty new to git.

Comment: from your screenshot, the library you are trying to use is in your home dir? you probably just need to import it in eclipse, then (and refer it as another project in the buildpath)

Comment: Here is great answer for your question.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the git repo to the *Java Build Path* in Eclipse.

Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Class Folder -> Add the git repo folder, starting from the parent of "com/flickr" folder here.

Alternatively, 
Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add *External* Class Folder -> Add the git repo folder, starting from the parent of "com/flickr" folder here.

Clean and compile your project after adding the git repo to Java Build Path.

Comment: Thank you. I've spent hours on this, and it was that simple. I appreciate your help!