# Compiling Bukkit plugin from GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to compile a plugin for Bukkit and I cant seem to get it to work. I have copied some code from github ["GitHub Code"](https://github.com/addstar/BlockHunt) and have imported it into eclipse as a maven project. When I try and do run-as 'Maven Build' it displays lot of text but finally gives me these errors.

```
Failed to execute goal on project BlockHunt: Could not resolve dependencies for project nl.Steffion:BlockHunt:jar:0.2.1-    
b${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: Failed to collect dependencies at org.bukkit:bukkit:jar:1.7.9-R0.2-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.bukkit:bukkit:jar:1.7.9-R0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.bukkit:bukkit:pom:1.7.9-
R0.2-SNAPSHOT from/to bukkit-maven (http://repo.bukkit.org/content/repositories/releases/): Access denied     
to http://repo.bukkit.org/content/repositories/releases/org/bukkit/bukkit/1.7.9-R0.2-SNAPSHOT/bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom.
```

I read in another post that I can put "dependency:copy-dependencies" in my run configurations for maven and its supposed try and download the stuff i need but it says access denied. I have never used maven or github so this is all new to me but it seems it should be really simple. All I really want to do is download the the code and create a jar file with it so I can use it. If anyone can point me in the right direction to making a jar from the code that would be great.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6760785/2767207), it may not specifically solve this problem, but it could help you get the code off of Github and into Eclipse correctly.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I checked out the link and followed it and it seems to have worked! So thank you very much! :)

Comment: No problem :) I'll post this as an answer so other users can see it

Comment: What does your POM look like?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin developer was getting the JavaDocs from the bukkit website, instead of downloading the jar and accessing it locally.

> You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760785/2767207), it may not specifically solve this problem, but it could help you get the code off of Github and into Eclipse correctly. –  [Jojodmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767207/jojodmo) yesterday

- His example showed you how to link to it locally.

Sometimes bukkit make some of their builds 'private', they do this to stop people downloading builds that did not pass the testing phase.

- Remember that the link they are using is 1.7.9. At this time 1.8.1 is out so you might want to use the latest version.