# Importing project in Eclipse from external project

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I write a programm in eclipse. Faced the following problem: I want to use some external project, which is placed on the github.
I didn't find complete answer about how to do this WITHOUT maven.

The first way, that I supposed to be the simplest was to connect to git repository and then export project. But eclipse doesn't see it as a project.

The second way is to just download all the files and somehow insert it in project. They includes:
.editconfig, .gitignore, .travis, build.xml, infinitest.filters, pom.xml

https://github.com/codecentric/jbehave-junit-runner - here is the link.
So there are some files that eclipse (and not only eclipse) uses to communicate with project.

I can just copy all the source files to the source folder and use all classes i need, but that means I will do this all by my hands.

So the question is: how to easily and naturally create a project from that git-project without using maven?

Comment: Well, what you are asking is essentially: "How do I import a Maven project in Eclipse without using Maven."

Comment: check this post [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to copy the files and then use Import--->File System.
It was necessary also to move all the packages with .java files from src/main/ to just src/. Which is logical, because the project classpath is set to src/ and so eclipse thinks that main is also a parent package => package declarations in all classes didn't match to it.