# Java Project - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to import this [repository](https://github.com/wizardjedi/smpp-test-tools/tree/master/smpp-multiplexer) as a java project in Eclipse but eclipse doesn't recognize it as a valid project.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is a maven project. You need to create project by own and import files in it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, this is a Maven project. You can use Maven to generate an Eclipse project and import that.

1. Install [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)
2. In the project directory  run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
3. Import project directory into Eclipse

---

According to the comments and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse), newer versions of Eclipse allow you to simple import it from the import menu. Just select Maven as the import source in the wizard and then select Existing Maven Projects.

Comment: Do not use `eclipse:eclipse` it's deprecated. Better use direct import in Eclipse