# Import project from Bitbucket to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, import, bitbucket

Let's say I have a project on BitBucket and want to add it into Eclipse of my coworker. His Eclipse has no projects now.

How can we import this project by using GUI (not a command line)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it.

[Importing a GitHub project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse)

At the uri section, paste your bitbucket project uri.