# How to show all files in Eclipse navigator/explorer?

Tags: eclipse, file, editor, hidden

I do not see some of my files in the Eclipse Navigator view (or Projet Explorer or PyDev Package Explorer).

I tried to go to "Customize View..." and remove all filters. It didn't show **.pickle* files, but it did unhide some other file types (*.** resources).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files

Comment: @anothem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files doesn't help showing *\*.pickle* files, but *.\** files.

Comment: Yup, should've read that more carefully; my bad. So it shoes *some* files with that extension and not others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember to refresh the view: Right-click the background of the Explorer/Navigator view to open a context menu, then choose "Refresh" (F5).

Restarting Eclipse doesn't help.

Comment: If that's the case, it's probably worth setting the auto-refresh in the preferences (type 'refresh' in the preferences to see the places that need to be changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Working Set, you can try the similar procedure that helped me with PHP Explorer and Navigator.

Look for the answer with pictures here:
[Folders and files don't appear in PHP Explorer in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405451/folders-and-files-dont-appear-in-php-explorer-in-eclipse-ide/27875149#27875149)