# Check-in .project file to GitHub repository

Tags: eclipse, github, checkin

I'm using LiClipse which is based on Eclipse. With EGit, I pushed most of the files and  directories into a GitHub repository.

However, there is one file that I can not find a way to check in to the repository: **.project**, the XML file.

How do I check in this file? Even manually?

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore at the root of your project ? can you post the content of this file? you may need to remove a line from that file to push .project into github. However, it is not really recommanded to check in files related to your IDE in your source code.

Comment: Thank you guys! By commenting .project in .gitignore, I can checkin it into GitHub now. Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can (from a command-line git session) add a .project, but you can't from Eclispe, because Eclipse filters by default the "resource files", ie the '`.*`' files.

If that is the case, see "[How can I get Eclipse to show `.*` files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98634/6309)".

Then, if that file isn't ignored by git, you can add it.
Or you can force the add (at least in command line: `git add --force`)