# How do I make Javadoc files show in Eclipse Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, adt, javadoc, egit

I'm using the Android Developer Tools wrapper of Eclipse, and the EGit git plugin for Eclipse. I'm having a problem where I'm generating Javadoc, but I can't find it in the package explorer.

I go to Project->Generate Javadoc.

I'm using C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javadoc.exe as my Javadoc command, and I select the package I want to generate Javadoc for.

I select the standard doclet with the following destination, where ReverseSentence is my package.
C:\Users\myname\workspace\ReverseSentence\doc

I check "open generated index file in browser", and generate the javadoc. It generates the Javadoc with no errors, and the index shows up in the main section of eclipse. However, the files don't show up in the package explorer.

I searched in the workspace through opening up the folder, and inside workspace\ReverseSentence there is a folder doc, which contains the proper Javadoc. However it isn't showing up in the package explorer.

How do I make it show up in the package explorer? When I used the regular version of Eclipse in the past (not the android developer tools wrapper), the Javadocs showed up there automatically.

What I've tried:

- refreshing the project
- closing and restarting eclipse
- generating the Javadoc with an older version of the Javadoc command, which was what I was using in the other version of eclipse last time it worked (jdk1.6.0_43)
- deleting the doc folder, recreating it, then trying to generate the javadoc in it (it generated in it but did not show up)
- unchecking the filters which hide some things in the package explorer, (as shown how to do here: [How can I get Eclipse to show .* files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files?rq=1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is the destination folder/directory for your Javadoc files once they are generated. I encountered this same problem and discovered (finally) that the Javadocs were getting sent to a different folder than my package files were in. They went to the workspace folder I thought held all of my code also, but the code was going into a different repository. Maybe try looking for your code's location and then seeing if the generated Javadocs are landing somewhere else when they are generated. If this is the case, then the fix is to regenerate and send to the code's directory. This way, Package Explorer should be able to find and display them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by sending the Javadocs to the code's directory?

Comment: Thank you! My code was in my local Git repo, not in my workspace. I've never worked with Git and eclipse or Java before, only Git and Rails.

Comment: @Magelet, maybe you should add to the original that you were using egit/git.

Comment: Yay! I'm glad this helped. I was very confused about what was going on until today. It's good to note this issue and its resolution for the future.

Comment: And to reply to @espertus, I meant to send the Javadocs (when regenerating) to the git directory where the code resides.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by refreshing the workspace or re-opening the eclipse !?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried both. I'll edit my question better to describe what I tried.

Comment: @NickT, I dont have enough reputation to comment. Sorry :( 
But, I answered it correctly I guess. Eclipse does not refresh the folder panel as far as I know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files?rq=1

Comment: That link wasn't actually helpful/relevant. I tried unchecking each checked box under the filters, and it didn't make the Javadocs show up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the filters in the settings of the explorer. If something does not show up, usually the filter hides it. The filter can be accessed in the drop down menu of Package Explorer.

Comment: I mentioned in the comment above, although perhaps should have edited to add to the question, I tried that. I tried unchecked every filter which was hiding stuff in the package explorer and it didn't make the Javadocs show up.