# Where I can edit .htaccess file in Eclipse?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to add some font(utf-8) in HtAccess file for use in Webview but I do not know where is this file in Eclipse project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Eclipse to show .\* files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files)